# MeteorJS: Error in Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, coffeescript

I have this code in client

```
Template['product'].events
  'click .addcart': (event, template) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    add_this = {"item": 1, "name": "test", "qty": 5, "price": 124}
    Meteor.call "Carts.push", add_this
   return
```

and in server

```
Meteor.methods
  'Carts.push': (params) ->
    console.log params
```

every time e click the button add cart I got an error in server side

> Exception while invoking method 'Carts.push' Error: Did not check()
>   all arguments during call to 'Carts.push'

Any idea why this error persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [`audit-argument-checks`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks) package installed, it's used to verify that you `check`ed all arguments passed to a method. `check`ing means testifying that an argument to a function is of the right type. You can just remove it with:

```
meteor remove audit-argument-checks
```

Or `check()` your arguments like [shown in the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks).